# Floating big elements next to each other?

Tags: css, position, element

Just a quick question regarding CSS positioning. I have several "segments" on my site which are 100% wide (fills the screen), and I want them floated next to each other. So only the first one will be visible, the other ones will be off-screen. I've tried playing around with positions and the overflow property without luck. Right now they just pop down below each other instead of floating.

This would work perfectly if the elements did not exceed the screen width, but as they do, they just pop down as I said earlier. I've tried setting a huge width to the "wrapper", something like 99999px. And then setting the segments to 100%, but that will just fill the whole 99999px width instead of the screen.

Any ideas?

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9xGPb/

Comment: do you have an html/css example (perhaps jsfiddle.net) of your layout?

Comment: Updated question, check the link.

Comment: Is the use of jQuery out of the question (DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NSaQn/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

**Example Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/zYE8p/)**

I used my favourite alternative to floats, `inline-blocks`

if you actually take it out of the fiddle  it has some pretty (gaudy?) colours which show that it allows for the `min-width: 900px;` on the centered_content div to work too, and I removed the absolute positioning for the menu so the content would go below it, for demo only but you may find it useful..

let me know if any good or if you have any questions

---

**Updated with some jQuery and to make corrections for default word-spacing**

#### New Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/8Y2Km/)

re: the IE6/7 hack rightly mentioned in the comments;

```
.segment {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
.segment {display: inline !ie7;}
```

needn't be a "parse hack" if that's your preference as long as that second rule is given to [lte IE 7] somehow, and separately at that it cannot be combined into the original rule with the `*` hack or anything, it won't work.. has to be in a separate ruleset.

I discovered word-spacing might be a problem if relying on width to hide, the natural behaviour of inline blocks is to put 3-4px between the elements like the space in between words, the workaround to this is to correct the word-spacing on the wrapper

```
.segment-wrapper {
   white-space: nowrap;
   word-spacing: -4px;
}
```

then restore it normal for the actual content divs, same place as you would restore the normal wrapping behaviour

```
.centered_content {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fcf;
    white-space: normal;
    word-spacing: 0;
}
```

and last, apart from this was fun.. there's 2 effects in that new fiddle - uncomment and comment the other.. forgive me I was playing! :)

Comment: That was what i was looking for! Thanks a bunch, i was beginning to think it was impossible with pure CSS.

Comment: oh cool thanks, I was working on some jQuery to go with it, I think you can "slide" or "animate" the width on this - am nearly there (I am jQ noob!) would you like me to post what I have when I get there.. I found that if you `#` the  portfolio link to "about" the same as the segment name, it should be easier.. but then you probably already know that! ~:)

Comment: Nice use of `inline-block` I dig it.  For those that must support legacy browsers (like myself) IE 6/7 may have problems per [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) ... "IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline."

Comment: @mdmullinax, thanks thought your jQuery was fab, you are right about `inline-block`, but there's a hack built into my fiddle for IE6/7 - it can be done for them too, just declare `display-inline` in separate rule for them can be hacked or put in conditional ;) - there is a caveat for the modern browsers (wrod-spacing) though so am going to post an updated fiddle with a couple jQ effects and CSS updates to allow for wordspacing

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of float is to try to float to the right or left unless there is not room for it.

This means that you cannot ever float an element off the page.

If you need to keep the element off the page, you will need to use a different positioning mechanism like `position: absolute`.

Comment: I have tried that. However, then i get a new problem. If i set it to position: absolute and give it a big width (so the elements float correctly), i don't know the width of the first element! Check the example link in the article (updated).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're creating a horizontal one-page portfolio.  I've recently been working on something similar.

Using your fiddle I've set the `.segment` class to

```
.segment {width:90%;height:90%;position:absolute;}
```

and then offset each `left` positioning further off the screen

```
#home {background-color:red;left:5%;}
#work {background-color:yellow;left:105%;}
#portfolio {background-color:green;left:205%;}
#contact {background-color:blue;left:305%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xGPb/2/

---

I also added some jQuery logic to switch views for the divs.

Comment: Yeah man you got it right, that's exactly what i'm doing and that's exactly what i needed. I knew i could do it this way before, but i wanted to see if there was any way to achieve this effect without needing to declare the "left" property for each segment. That would make it more dynamic. I ended up doing it this way, but Claire actually posted a better solution to it. I read it after i was done though, so i might not change it. Thanks for the help though, and nice work with the javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure which segments you want to start off the page but this jsfiddle uses positioning to shove the #two div off to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/EdAZP/1/

Which part of your example did you want to start off the page?

Comment: I knew i could do it this way, but i was hoping there was a way to do it without declaring the "left" property of each segment. I actually ended up using this method, and it's working now. Claire actually posted a better solution to this, but she posted it after i was done with this so i don't think i'm gonna bother to change it unless i need to. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just hide the other elements and toggle them with some javascript (jQuery is much easier)?

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I'm gonna use javascript to slide the segments later, that's the reason why i'm doing it this way...